# Lock free list remove operation

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking, lock-free

I have the following problem definition:

Design a lock-free simple linked list with the following operations:

- Add(item): add the node to the beginning (head) of the list
- Remove(item): remove the given item from the list

Below is shown the code implemented so far:

```
public class List<T>
{
    private readonly T _sentinel;
    private readonly Node<T> _head;

    public List()
    {
        _head = new Node<T>();
        _sentinel = default(T);
    }

    public List(T item)
    {
        _head = new Node<T>(item);
        _sentinel = item;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item);

        do
        {
            node.Next = _head.Next;
        }
        while (!Atomic.CAS(ref _head.Next, node.Next, node));
    }

    public void Remove(Node<T> item)
    {
        Node<T> next;
        Node<T> oldItem = item;  

        if (item.Value.Equals(_sentinel))
            return;

        item.Value = _sentinel;

        do
        {
            next = item.Next;

            if (next == null)
            {
                Atomic.CAS(ref item.Next, null, null);
                return;
            }

        } while (!Atomic.CAS(ref item.Next, next, next.Next));

        item.Value = next.Value;
    }
}
```

The head is actually a dummy (sentinel) node kept for ease of use. The practical head is actually _head.Next.
 The problem is on the remove operation when trying to remove the last element of the list:

[image]

On the remove part there are two cases:

1. The node has a following not-null next pointer: then do the CAS operation and steal the value data of the next item removing actually the next item
2. The problematic case is when the element to remove is the last one in the list:

   - Do Atomically: *If (item == oldItem and item.Next == null) then item = null* where oldItem is a pointer to the item to remove;

So I want to do is in the case of removing **C** node:

- if(**C**==old-C-reference and **C**.Next == null) then C = null => all atomically

The problem is that I have a CAS only on a single object. 
How can I solve this problem atomically? Or is there a better way of doing this remove operation that I'm missing out here?

Comment: Are you sure the _sentinel thing works? With value types there is no way to distinguish between default(T) and a potentially useful value. In other words the .NET type system does not provide you with a value usable as a sentinel.

Comment: Indeed the sentinel value may not work for value types, but for ease of use, let's just define a predefined marker as sentinel. If you know a better solution please do share away (https://gist.github.com/). However, my main trouble is on the remove operation.

Comment: Your remove makes no sense to me. If you want to remove B then you need to CAS A.next to C. Right? Your code does not do that. I admit it's the first time I'm working on an atomic linked list.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, when removing B we do a trick by copying C's contents to B and removing C: B.Next = C.Next (in the loop) and B.Value = C.Value after the move succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when removing B we do a trick by copying C's contents to B and removing C: B.Next = C.Next (in the loop) and B.Value = C.Value after the move succeeded

So you need to atomically modify two memory locations. CAS in .NET does not support that. You can, however, wrap those two values in another object that can be swapped out atomically:

```
class ValuePlusNext<T> {
 T Value;
 Node<T> Next;
}

class Node<T> {
 ValuePlusNext<T> Value;
}
```

Now you can write to both values in one atomic operation. `CAS(ref Value, new ValuePlusNext<T>(next.Value, next.Value.Next)`. Something like that.

It is strange that ValuePlusNext has the same structure that your old Node class had. In a sense you are now managing two physical linked list node for each logical one.

```
while (true) {
 var old = item.Value;
 var new = new ValuePlusNext(...);
 if (CAS(ref Value, old, new)) break;
}
```

Comment: This ain't going to work since it will only check for the reference and not the values within. I could freely change the node.Next value and the CAS with another node (or another reference to that node) will succeed since they have the same reference even though the node.Next value has changed.

Comment: CAS for reference types checks the memory location that a reference points to, but I'm interested in checking the value.

Comment: The ValuePlusNext fields are supposed to be never changed. If you want to change them create a new ValuePlusNext and CAS it into place. That way you can safely check and compare the fields. Does that work? You can then base the CAS update on the condition that the object reference to the ValuePlusNext object did not change in the meantime. I have added some code.

Comment: Almost ... The thing is that CAS works on the same type arguments and CAS(ref Value, old, new) won't compile => "new" is of different type than old and Value types.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All three should be of type ValuePlusNext.

Comment: Yep, my bad. It works ok for this problem and didn't understood correctly what you've meant. But I am now thinking if there is a better (or more elegant) way of getting rid of this nesting.

Comment: It seems convoluted but it's a standard technique to atomically update multiple locations. A simpler remove algorithm is, of course, to cut out the node to be deleted but that requires knowing the predecessor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91935/discussion-between-tamas-ionut-and-usr).